# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound on String split

Tags: java

I am splitting a String in a String array.

```
String a = "SomeString1, SomeString2 00000-0000";    
String[] b = a.split("(\\, )|(\\ )|(\\-)");
```

and assigning the array values like

```
String c = b[0];    
String d = b[1];   
String e = b[2];   
String f = b[3];
```

Which is giving an exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBound Array index Out of Range: 4`

Comment: Please show us more code. The message means that you are trying to access the element at index 4 within some array which doesn't have this. The code you have above wouldn't cause this failure.

Comment: @Trobbins: The double-backslashes became visible thx to your edit.

Comment: Thanks Guys!!!!!
I was trying to access the 4th variable which was not at all there.

Inference: The position which i was trying to access is mentioned as 
Array index Out of Range: 4